# Storage Permission Denied' Error in Flutter WebView

Tags: flutter, webview, permissions, storage

the app or WebView has not been granted the necessary permissions to read or write to external storage. This can load to complications when trying to perform tasks like file uploads or downloads within the WebView.

**This is my main.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(toolbarHeight: 0.1),
    body: WebViewWidget(),
  ),
 );
 }
 }
 class WebViewWidget extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _WebViewWidgetState createState() => _WebViewWidgetState();
 }

 class _WebViewWidgetState extends State<WebViewWidget> {
 final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
 Completer<WebViewController>();
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
 body: GestureDetector(
 onTap: () {
  print("This one doesn't print");
 },
 child: Container(
  child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: WebView(
              initialUrl:
                  'https://www.myhospitalnow.com/hospitals/',
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController 
    webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
               // Automatically trigger file selection
            },
              gestureRecognizers: Set()
                ..add(
                    Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => 
    TapGestureRecognizer()
                      ..onTapDown = (tap) {
                        print("This one prints");
                        _triggerFileSelection();
                      })),
            ),
          ),
        ],
       ),
       ],
       ),
       ),
       ),
       );
       }

       Future<void> _triggerFileSelection() async {
       try {
       print('_triggerFileSelection triggering file selection:');
       var status = await Permission.storage.request();
       if (status == PermissionStatus.granted) {
       // _pickImage();
       } else {
       print("Storage permission denied");
       // Handle permission denial (e.g., show a permission request 
      dialog)
      }
      } catch (e) {
      print('Error triggering file selection: $e');
      }
     }
     }
```

**This is flutter pubspec.yml**

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: '>=2.18.1 <3.0.0'


dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
webview_flutter: ^2.0.15
flutter_downloader: ^1.7.4
url_launcher: ^6.0.13
file_picker: ^4.1.4 
permission_handler: ^11.2.0 
image_picker: ^1.0.2

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
dio: ^5.4.0

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
file_picker: ^4.1.4
```

**This is my AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.webviewmyhospitalnow">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission 
android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:label="webviewmyhospitalnow"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
            android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
        />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category 
       android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
       </activity>
   
      <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />

      <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
      </provider>
    
     </application>

    </manifest>
```

**Error**

```
I/flutter ( 9118): This one prints
I/flutter ( 9118): _triggerFileSelection triggering file selection:
D/EGL_emulation( 9118): app_time_stats: avg=613.07ms min=110.38ms 
max=1115.77ms count=2
E/FrameEvents( 9118): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
D/EGL_emulation( 9118): app_time_stats: avg=501.37ms min=51.75ms 
max=1335.84ms count=3
D/EGL_emulation( 9118): app_time_stats: avg=513.31ms min=59.96ms 
max=1371.12ms count=3
2
E/FrameEvents( 9118): updateAcquireFence: Did not find frame.
I/flutter ( 9118): Storage permission denied
```

Choose buttons should work properly and upload, download also,